# Ldap mapping users and groups

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I have some question about mapping users in openldap. Is it possible to set somethings like this:

Group 1:
cn=groups_name1,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com and some memberUid in this group:
memberUid: test

And in second group, some other user:

Group 2:
cn=groups_name2,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com and some memberUid in this group:
memberUid: test2

And after that set some projects and access to it:

cn=projects_name,ou=projects,dc=company,dc=com and in this project memberUid: cn=groups_name1,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The restriction is that POSIX groups can contain only users, not other groups.

Depending on what you want to do, NIS netgroups allow other netgroups as members.

Comment: Waht do you think about alias? It will be go for this?